# What are common pre-processing steps of EEG signals

Tags: signal-analysis, eeg, preprocessing

I am new to EEG analysis, and I wonder what are the common pre-processing steps of EEG signals, for example, for motor imagery classification?

Currently, my pre-processing steps include

1. Epoch the data
2. Filter the data
3. Down-sample the data
4. Do baseline correction
5. Do common average reference
6. Do scaling

Are they appropriate or able to be improved further?

Thanks for any suggestion in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorials of EEGLAB or Fieldtrip?